# SQlite database data instead of shared preference data

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I have been using shared preferences to save highscores. I need to change it to work with an sqlite database but I have no idea what to do. Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: what is your problem? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know really what your problem is.. but maybe this tutorial will help (?)

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I just need help changing the way i save highscores, ive been using shared preferences. But i need to be able to save the highscores to sqlite database and display data

Comment: Reading that tutorial will help you understand how to use SQLite databases. Spoon-feeding you code will teach you nothing.

Comment: @AndrewFielden i know i didnt intend to seem like i want to be spoon fed code, im just in a panic to get this done and im just lost when it comes to databases, i can never make sense of it. i would just really appreciate help right now, im in panic mode

Comment: This place is so inconsistent. I just got downvotes for answering with a link, and this guy gets upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic. The DB table you need is relatively simple. The things you need to understand are:-

- How to create the database and table
- How to put data in the table
- how to get data out of the table (query)

If you read through the link provided in the other answer, it explains how to do all this with a simple example.

In your case, the DB table you need is really simple. Suggest something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create high scores table
    String CREATE_HIGH_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE high_scores ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "user_name TEXT, "+
            "high_score INTEGER )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_HIGH_SCORE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: The lack of response to this helpful answer perhaps indicates that zero-effort questions are not usually worth answering `;-)`. Am voting to close as too broad.